# Can't start intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a problem by sending an Intent.
In my project, the activity passes two values (username, password) in a method to another class. This class should create an intent and put extra the values of the variables username and password and then should start this intent.

My problem is, that it it not possible for me, to perform this action. I've no idea why...can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: please add logcat error

Comment: you should add `startActivity(dataForLoginRequest)` after putting extra data to intent

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: I'm sry! @MikeM. The next time, I'll post my code as text.

Comment: That's the problem @masoudvali! It is not possible to call this method inside this scope...

Comment: Please correct this one. There is an [edit] link under the tags below your question, to the left.

Comment: if you have access to context use context.startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("username","username");
                intent.putExtra("password","password");
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

you'll need a context reference and then call "startActivity()" with that context.